# Preparing for Magento 2 Associate Developer Certification

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Hi am preparing for Magento 2 certification and need a lot of support from the community if anyone knows some best dumps that I could purchase will be helpful.

**NO.7 You are implementing a before plugin in MyCompany_Magic. It will intercept the same method
that MyCompany_Admission is already intercepting using a before plugin: Topmenu::getBlockHtml
Which two actions are required to ensure the new plugin will execute last? (Choose two.)**

**A**. Configure plugin sequencing for both plugins in MyCompany_Magic's etc/plugin_sequence.xml
file

**B**. Add MyCompany_Admission as a dependency in MyCompany_Magic's etc/module.xml file

**C**. Set a sortOrder="10" for MyCompany_Admission's plugin in MyCompany_Magic's etc/di.xml

**D**. Include a sortOrder="20" on the new plugin in MyCompany_Magic's etc/di.xml file

**Answer: B, C**

I can understand that I need to give dependency so I can get that the answer b is correct but I don't understand the concept with the option c.

**Can anyone please explain it to me**

Comment: I think the answer here is C and D because for plugin execution, sort order is the way plugin can be executed. Dependency means the module will load in that order. Can someone correct me if i am wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency in the module.xml file will ensure the module load order.

`sortOrder` in the plugin tag in di.xml will ensure the actual plugin execution order.

```
<plugin name="{pluginName}" type="{PluginClassName}" sortOrder="1" />
```

Dependency in the module.xml doesn't ensure the plugin execution order.

For more information, you can check https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

**UPDATE**

Suppose I have two plugins (example after plugin) for the same method.

Plugin 1

```
<plugin name="{pluginName1}" type="{PluginClassName1}" sortOrder="1" />
```

Plugin 2

```
<plugin name="{pluginName2}" type="{PluginClassName2}" sortOrder="2" />
```

Then based on the sort order Plugin 1 will execute first and then the Plugin 2.

Comment: Set a sortOrder="10" for MyCompany_Admission's plugin in MyCompany_Magic's etc/di.xml  hi i was enwuiring about this option

Comment: Yes, the sortOrder is the correct way to ensure the plugin execution order.

Comment: Thanks for the update now its more clear